# How to Exclude Null Values from update_attributes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I am trying to handle a Stripe Webhook for Invoice.created and want to save the invoice line item. My challenge is that the files variables change based on the line item type.

I received a `undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass` when I tried to import the line items since, depending on the type of line item, the plan object could be null.

I was able to solve the problem by separating the update_attributes into 2, one would only happen if the plan object exists. The following is what I was to get to work.  My hope is that there is a better way.

```
  @invoice_line_item = InvoiceLineItem.where(stripe_line_item_id: line_item.id).first_or_create(invoice_id: @invoice.id)
  @invoice_line_item.update_attributes(
    amount: line_item.amount,
    currency: line_item.currency,
    period_start: Time.at(line_item.period.start).strftime("%m-%d-%Y"),
    period_end: Time.at(line_item.period.end).strftime("%m-%d-%Y"),
    proration: line_item.proration,
    item_type: line_item.type)
  if line_item.plan.present?
    @invoice_line_item.update_attributes(
      plan_name: line_item.plan.name,
      plan_interval: line_item.plan.interval,
      plan_amount: line_item.plan.amount,
      trial_period_days: line_item.plan.trial_period_days)
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

`line_item.plan.try(:name)`

and similarly for all the `line_item.plan` elements

Try (in rails) will give you nil if the subject is nil http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try

It's not really excluding the nil values, but if `line_item.plan` is nil, then the sub-values will also be `nil`.  If that's the right behavior, then you should try `try`.

Update:  I just hit on this coderwall post this morning (https://coderwall.com/p/wamyow) which mentions the use of `delegate` with `allow_nil: true`.  Could you do something like

```
class InvoiceLineItem < ActiveRecord::Base

  delegate :name, :interval, :amount, :trial_period_days, to: :plan, allow_nil: true

  ... rest of the class ...

end
```

Then looking more closely, I wonder why you're updating all the `plan` attributes on the `line_item` if they are available via the relationship?  Am I missing something?

Comment: The plan object is part of the hash that comes from stripe. I don't have a plan model in my app. The plan is used by stripe when you have a charge for a subscription plan. If you bill for a non subscription charge the plan object in the hash is null. Trying the try now.